# opencart to show category for each product in search results page

Tags: php, opencart

I am using Opencart 2.2.0 and I am trying to show category for each product on search page. So far, I have my controller like this:

```
<?php
class ControllerProductSearch extends Controller {
    public function index() {
        $this->load->language('product/search');

        $this->load->model('catalog/category');

        $this->load->model('catalog/product');

        $this->load->model('tool/image');

        if (isset($this->request->get['search'])) {
            $search = $this->request->get['search'];
        } else {
            $search = '';
        }

        if (isset($this->request->get['tag'])) {
            $tag = $this->request->get['tag'];
        } elseif (isset($this->request->get['search'])) {
            $tag = $this->request->get['search'];

        } else {
            $tag = '';
        }

        if (isset($this->request->get['description'])) {
            $description = $this->request->get['description'];
        } else {
            $description = '';
        }

        if (isset($this->request->get['category_id'])) {
            $category_id = $this->request->get['category_id'];
        } else {
            $category_id = 0;
        }

        if (isset($this->request->get['sub_category'])) {
            $sub_category = $this->request->get['sub_category'];
        } else {
            $sub_category = '';
        }

        if (isset($this->request->get['sort'])) {
            $sort = $this->request->get['sort'];
        } else {
            $sort = 'p.sort_order';
        }

        if (isset($this->request->get['order'])) {
            $order = $this->request->get['order'];
        } else {
            $order = 'ASC';
        }

        if (isset($this->request->get['page'])) {
            $page = $this->request->get['page'];
        } else {
            $page = 1;
        }

        if (isset($this->request->get['limit'])) {
            $limit = (int)$this->request->get['limit'];
        } else {
            $limit = $this->config->get($this->config->get('config_theme') . '_product_limit');
        }

        if (isset($this->request->get['search'])) {
            $this->document->setTitle($this->language->get('heading_title') .  ' - ' . $this->request->get['search']);
        } elseif (isset($this->request->get['tag'])) {
            $this->document->setTitle($this->language->get('heading_title') .  ' - ' . $this->language->get('heading_tag') . $this->request->get['tag']);
        } else {
            $this->document->setTitle($this->language->get('heading_title'));
        }

        $data['breadcrumbs'] = array();

        $data['breadcrumbs'][] = array(
            'text' => $this->language->get('text_home'),
            'href' => $this->url->link('common/home')
        );

        $url = '';

        if (isset($this->request->get['search'])) {
            $url .= '&search=' . urlencode(html_entity_decode($this->request->get['search'], ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8'));
        }

        if (isset($this->request->get['tag'])) {
            $url .= '&tag=' . urlencode(html_entity_decode($this->request->get['tag'], ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8'));
        }

        if (isset($this->request->get['description'])) {
            $url .= '&description=' . $this->request->get['description'];
        }

        if (isset($this->request->get['category_id'])) {
            $url .= '&category_id=' . $this->request->get['category_id'];
        }

        if (isset($this->request->get['sub_category'])) {
            $url .= '&sub_category=' . $this->request->get['sub_category'];
        }

        if (isset($this->request->get['sort'])) {
            $url .= '&sort=' . $this->request->get['sort'];
        }

        if (isset($this->request->get['order'])) {
            $url .= '&order=' . $this->request->get['order'];
        }

        if (isset($this->request->get['page'])) {
            $url .= '&page=' . $this->request->get['page'];
        }

        if (isset($this->request->get['limit'])) {
            $url .= '&limit=' . $this->request->get['limit'];
        }

        $data['breadcrumbs'][] = array(
            'text' => $this->language->get('heading_title'),
            'href' => $this->url->link('product/search', $url)
        );

        if (isset($this->request->get['search'])) {
            $data['heading_title'] = $this->language->get('heading_title') .  ' - ' . $this->request->get['search'];
        } else {
            $data['heading_title'] = $this->language->get('heading_title');
        }
        $data['customer_group_id'] = $this->customer->getGroupId();

$data['logged'] = $this->customer->isLogged();
        $data['text_empty'] = $this->language->get('text_empty');
        $data['text_search'] = $this->language->get('text_search');
        $data['text_keyword'] = $this->language->get('text_keyword');
        $data['text_category'] = $this->language->get('text_category');
        $data['text_sub_category'] = $this->language->get('text_sub_category');
        $data['text_quantity'] = $this->language->get('text_quantity');
        $data['text_manufacturer'] = $this->language->get('text_manufacturer');
        $data['text_model'] = $this->language->get('text_model');
        $data['text_price'] = $this->language->get('text_price');
        $data['text_wholesale'] = $this->language->get('text_wholesale');
        $data['text_tax'] = $this->language->get('text_tax');
        $data['text_points'] = $this->language->get('text_points');
        $data['text_compare'] = sprintf($this->language->get('text_compare'), (isset($this->session->data['compare']) ? count($this->session->data['compare']) : 0));
        $data['text_sort'] = $this->language->get('text_sort');
        $data['text_limit'] = $this->language->get('text_limit');

        $data['entry_search'] = $this->language->get('entry_search');
        $data['entry_description'] = $this->language->get('entry_description');

        $data['button_search'] = $this->language->get('button_search');
        $data['button_cart'] = $this->language->get('button_cart');
        $data['button_wishlist'] = $this->language->get('button_wishlist');
        $data['button_compare'] = $this->language->get('button_compare');
        $data['button_list'] = $this->language->get('button_list');
        $data['button_grid'] = $this->language->get('button_grid');

        $data['compare'] = $this->url->link('product/compare');

        $this->load->model('catalog/category');

            $cart_product_detail=$this->cart->getProducts();
           //print_r($cart_product_detail);
           $data['cart_product_info']=array();
           foreach($cart_product_detail as $cart_info){
            //print_r($cart_info);
            $data['cart_product_info'][] = array(
                'cart_product_id'  => $cart_info['product_id'],
                'cart_product_qty' => $cart_info['quantity']
            );
           }


        // 3 Level Category Search
        $data['categories'] = array();

        $categories_1 = $this->model_catalog_category->getCategories(0);

        foreach ($categories_1 as $category_1) {
            $level_2_data = array();

            $categories_2 = $this->model_catalog_category->getCategories($category_1['category_id']);

            foreach ($categories_2 as $category_2) {
                $level_3_data = array();

                $categories_3 = $this->model_catalog_category->getCategories($category_2['category_id']);

                foreach ($categories_3 as $category_3) {
                    $level_3_data[] = array(
                        'category_id' => $category_3['category_id'],
                        'name'        => $category_3['name'],
                    );
                }

                $level_2_data[] = array(
                    'category_id' => $category_2['category_id'],
                    'name'        => $category_2['name'],
                    'children'    => $level_3_data
                );
            }

            $data['categories'][] = array(
                'category_id' => $category_1['category_id'],
                'name'        => $category_1['name'],
                'children'    => $level_2_data
            );
        }

        $data['products'] = array();

        if (isset($this->request->get['search']) || isset($this->request->get['tag'])) {
            $filter_data = array(
                'filter_name'         => $search,
                'filter_tag'          => $tag,
                'filter_description'  => $description,
                'filter_category_id'  => $category_id,
                'filter_sub_category' => $sub_category,
                'sort'                => $sort,
                'order'               => $order,
                'start'               => ($page - 1) * $limit,
                'limit'               => $limit
            );

            $product_total = $this->model_catalog_product->getTotalProducts($filter_data);

            $results = $this->model_catalog_product->getProducts($filter_data);

            foreach ($results as $result) {
                if ($result['image']) {
                    $image = $this->model_tool_image->resize($result['image'], $this->config->get($this->config->get('config_theme') . '_image_product_width'), $this->config->get($this->config->get('config_theme') . '_image_product_height'));
                } else {
                    $image = $this->model_tool_image->resize('placeholder.png', $this->config->get($this->config->get('config_theme') . '_image_product_width'), $this->config->get($this->config->get('config_theme') . '_image_product_height'));
                }

                if ($this->customer->isLogged() || !$this->config->get('config_customer_price')) {
                    $price = $this->currency->format($this->tax->calculate($result['price'], $result['tax_class_id'], $this->config->get('config_tax')), $this->session->data['currency']);
                    $wholesale = $this->currency->format($this->tax->calculate($result['wholesale'], $result['tax_class_id'], $this->config->get('config_tax')), $this->session->data['currency']);

                } else {
                    $price = false;
                    $wholesale = false;
                }

                if ((float)$result['special']) {
                    $special = $this->currency->format($this->tax->calculate($result['special'], $result['tax_class_id'], $this->config->get('config_tax')), $this->session->data['currency']);
                } else {
                    $special = false;
                }

                if ($this->config->get('config_tax')) {
                    $tax = $this->currency->format((float)$result['special'] ? $result['special'] : $result['price'], $this->session->data['currency']);
                } else {
                    $tax = false;
                }

                if ($this->config->get('config_review_status')) {
                    $rating = (int)$result['rating'];
                } else {
                    $rating = false;
                }

                $data['products'][] = array(
                    'product_id'  => $result['product_id'],
                    'thumb'       => $image,
                    'name'        => $result['name'],
                    'description' => utf8_substr(strip_tags(html_entity_decode($result['description'], ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8')), 0, $this->config->get($this->config->get('config_theme') . '_product_description_length')) . '..',
                    'price'       => $price,
                    'wholesale'   => $wholesale,
                    'special'     => $special,
                    'tax'         => $tax,
                    'upc'         => $result['upc'],
                    'minimum'     => $result['minimum'] > 0 ? $result['minimum'] : 1,
                    'rating'      => $result['rating'],
                    'href'        => $this->url->link('product/product', 'product_id=' . $result['product_id'] . $url)
                );
            }

            $url = '';

            if (isset($this->request->get['search'])) {
                $url .= '&search=' . urlencode(html_entity_decode($this->request->get['search'], ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8'));
            }

            if (isset($this->request->get['tag'])) {
                $url .= '&tag=' . urlencode(html_entity_decode($this->request->get['tag'], ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8'));
            }

            if (isset($this->request->get['description'])) {
                $url .= '&description=' . $this->request->get['description'];
            }

            if (isset($this->request->get['category_id'])) {
                $url .= '&category_id=' . $this->request->get['category_id'];
            }

            if (isset($this->request->get['sub_category'])) {
                $url .= '&sub_category=' . $this->request->get['sub_category'];
            }

            if (isset($this->request->get['limit'])) {
                $url .= '&limit=' . $this->request->get['limit'];
            }

            $data['sorts'] = array();

            $data['sorts'][] = array(
                'text'  => $this->language->get('text_default'),
                'value' => 'p.sort_order-ASC',
                'href'  => $this->url->link('product/search', 'sort=p.sort_order&order=ASC' . $url)
            );

            $data['sorts'][] = array(
                'text'  => $this->language->get('text_name_asc'),
                'value' => 'pd.name-ASC',
                'href'  => $this->url->link('product/search', 'sort=pd.name&order=ASC' . $url)
            );

            $data['sorts'][] = array(
                'text'  => $this->language->get('text_name_desc'),
                'value' => 'pd.name-DESC',
                'href'  => $this->url->link('product/search', 'sort=pd.name&order=DESC' . $url)
            );

            $data['sorts'][] = array(
                'text'  => $this->language->get('text_price_asc'),
                'value' => 'p.price-ASC',
                'href'  => $this->url->link('product/search', 'sort=p.price&order=ASC' . $url)
            );

            $data['sorts'][] = array(
                'text'  => $this->language->get('text_price_desc'),
                'value' => 'p.price-DESC',
                'href'  => $this->url->link('product/search', 'sort=p.price&order=DESC' . $url)
            );

            if ($this->config->get('config_review_status')) {
                $data['sorts'][] = array(
                    'text'  => $this->language->get('text_rating_desc'),
                    'value' => 'rating-DESC',
                    'href'  => $this->url->link('product/search', 'sort=rating&order=DESC' . $url)
                );

                $data['sorts'][] = array(
                    'text'  => $this->language->get('text_rating_asc'),
                    'value' => 'rating-ASC',
                    'href'  => $this->url->link('product/search', 'sort=rating&order=ASC' . $url)
                );
            }

            $data['sorts'][] = array(
                'text'  => $this->language->get('text_model_asc'),
                'value' => 'p.model-ASC',
                'href'  => $this->url->link('product/search', 'sort=p.model&order=ASC' . $url)
            );

            $data['sorts'][] = array(
                'text'  => $this->language->get('text_model_desc'),
                'value' => 'p.model-DESC',
                'href'  => $this->url->link('product/search', 'sort=p.model&order=DESC' . $url)
            );

            $url = '';

            if (isset($this->request->get['search'])) {
                $url .= '&search=' . urlencode(html_entity_decode($this->request->get['search'], ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8'));
            }

            if (isset($this->request->get['tag'])) {
                $url .= '&tag=' . urlencode(html_entity_decode($this->request->get['tag'], ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8'));
            }

            if (isset($this->request->get['description'])) {
                $url .= '&description=' . $this->request->get['description'];
            }

            if (isset($this->request->get['category_id'])) {
                $url .= '&category_id=' . $this->request->get['category_id'];
            }

            if (isset($this->request->get['sub_category'])) {
                $url .= '&sub_category=' . $this->request->get['sub_category'];
            }

            if (isset($this->request->get['sort'])) {
                $url .= '&sort=' . $this->request->get['sort'];
            }

            if (isset($this->request->get['order'])) {
                $url .= '&order=' . $this->request->get['order'];
            }

            $data['limits'] = array();

            $limits = array_unique(array($this->config->get($this->config->get('config_theme') . '_product_limit'), 25, 50, 75, 100));

            sort($limits);

            foreach($limits as $value) {
                $data['limits'][] = array(
                    'text'  => $value,
                    'value' => $value,
                    'href'  => $this->url->link('product/search', $url . '&limit=' . $value)
                );
            }

            $url = '';

            if (isset($this->request->get['search'])) {
                $url .= '&search=' . urlencode(html_entity_decode($this->request->get['search'], ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8'));
            }

            if (isset($this->request->get['tag'])) {
                $url .= '&tag=' . urlencode(html_entity_decode($this->request->get['tag'], ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8'));
            }

            if (isset($this->request->get['description'])) {
                $url .= '&description=' . $this->request->get['description'];
            }

            if (isset($this->request->get['category_id'])) {
                $url .= '&category_id=' . $this->request->get['category_id'];
            }

            if (isset($this->request->get['sub_category'])) {
                $url .= '&sub_category=' . $this->request->get['sub_category'];
            }

            if (isset($this->request->get['sort'])) {
                $url .= '&sort=' . $this->request->get['sort'];
            }

            if (isset($this->request->get['order'])) {
                $url .= '&order=' . $this->request->get['order'];
            }

            if (isset($this->request->get['limit'])) {
                $url .= '&limit=' . $this->request->get['limit'];
            }

            $pagination = new Pagination();
            $pagination->total = $product_total;
            $pagination->page = $page;
            $pagination->limit = $limit;
            $pagination->url = $this->url->link('product/search', $url . '&page={page}');

            $data['pagination'] = $pagination->render();

            $data['results'] = sprintf($this->language->get('text_pagination'), ($product_total) ? (($page - 1) * $limit) + 1 : 0, ((($page - 1) * $limit) > ($product_total - $limit)) ? $product_total : ((($page - 1) * $limit) + $limit), $product_total, ceil($product_total / $limit));

            // http://googlewebmastercentral.blogspot.com/2011/09/pagination-with-relnext-and-relprev.html
            if ($page == 1) {
                $this->document->addLink($this->url->link('product/search', '', true), 'canonical');
            } elseif ($page == 2) {
                $this->document->addLink($this->url->link('product/search', '', true), 'prev');
            } else {
                $this->document->addLink($this->url->link('product/search', $url . '&page='. ($page - 1), true), 'prev');
            }

            if ($limit && ceil($product_total / $limit) > $page) {
                $this->document->addLink($this->url->link('product/search', $url . '&page='. ($page + 1), true), 'next');
            }
        }

        $data['search'] = $search;
        $data['description'] = $description;
        $data['category_id'] = $category_id;
        $data['sub_category'] = $sub_category;

        $data['sort'] = $sort;
        $data['order'] = $order;
        $data['limit'] = $limit;

        $data['column_left'] = $this->load->controller('common/column_left');
        $data['column_right'] = $this->load->controller('common/column_right');
        $data['content_top'] = $this->load->controller('common/content_top');
        $data['content_bottom'] = $this->load->controller('common/content_bottom');
        $data['footer'] = $this->load->controller('common/footer');
        $data['header'] = $this->load->controller('common/header');

        $this->response->setOutput($this->load->view('product/search', $data));
    }


}
```

But I do not know how to show the categories for each product. Any suggestions? Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your controller file, find: `$data['products'][] = array(`

before it add:

```
        $product_categories = array();
        // get categories of each product, based on product id
        $categories = $this->model_catalog_product->getCategories($result['product_id']);
        if($categories){
            // select each category name and create a link to it
            foreach($categories as $category){
                $category_info = $this->model_catalog_category->getCategory($category['category_id']);
                $product_categories[] = array(
                    'name' => $category_info['name'],
                    'href' => $this->url->link('product/category', 'path=' . $category_info['category_id'] )
                );
            }
        }
```

after it add:

```
            // store categories information 
            'product_categories' => $product_categories,
```

Your code must be like this:

```
            $product_categories = array();
            // get categories of each product, based on product id
            $categories = $this->model_catalog_product->getCategories($result['product_id']);
            if($categories){
                // select each category name and create a link to it
                foreach($categories as $category){
                    $category_info = $this->model_catalog_category->getCategory($category['category_id']);
                    $product_categories[] = array(
                        'name' => $category_info['name'],
                        'href' => $this->url->link('product/category', 'path=' . $category_info['category_id'] )
                    );
                }
            }

            $data['products'][] = array(
                // store categories information 
                'product_categories' => $product_categories,
                'product_id'  => $result['product_id'],
                'thumb'       => $image,
                'name'        => $result['name'],
                'description' => utf8_substr(strip_tags(html_entity_decode($result['description'], ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8')), 0, $this->config->get($this->config->get('config_theme') . '_product_description_length')) . '..',
                'price'       => $price,
                'special'     => $special,
                'tax'         => $tax,
                'minimum'     => $result['minimum'] > 0 ? $result['minimum'] : 1,
                'rating'      => $result['rating'],
                'href'        => $this->url->link('product/product', 'product_id=' . $result['product_id'] . $url)
            );
```

Now open your template file:

```
catalog\view\theme\default\template\product\search.tpl
```

find:

```
<?php if ($product['rating']) { ?>
```

add before it:

```
    <?php if($product['product_categories']){ ?>
        <div class="product-categories">
            <?php foreach($product['product_categories'] as $category){ ?>
                <a href="<?php echo $category['href']; ?>" title="<?php echo $category['name']; ?>"><?php echo $category['name']; ?></a> &nbsp;
            <?php } ?>
        </div>
    <?php } ?>
```

Comment: Thank you so much for the reply, I can see the categories and subcategories now for each product, but I am getting the following errors as well:

Notice: Undefined index: name in /catalog/controller/product/search.php on line 273

Notice: Undefined index: category_id in /catalog/controller/product/search.php on line 274

Comment: Ok, It seems you have some products in your search result that they have not any category, I'll edit my post, wait.

Comment: I've edited my post, I also noticed that you modified controller file, I see `wholesale` in product array that is not part of original Opencart. maybe your modification caused error.  I've tested my code on a fresh Opencart 2.2.0.0 with no error.

Comment: It is just an oc_product table field I added in order to show the wholesale price to logged users. I still can't get this to work, I am getting the same error as before. Do you have any suggestion as to what can i try? Thanx.

Comment: I see them on front end of my web page. But they are like I told you in my previous comment: In my controller file, because the errors are:

Notice: Undefined index: name in /catalog/controller/product/search.php on line 273 

Notice: Undefined index: category_id in /catalog/controller/product/search.php on line 274

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/129042/discussion-between-mojtaba-sabeti-and-nancy).

Comment: Hey @Nancy, as my answer works fine on a fresh installation of Opencart, can you accept it?

Comment: Hi, I just did.

Comment: I wanted to let you know what the problem was with my code. I just needed to add  if(!empty($category_info)) bellow the beginning of foreach loop. meaning, I needed to check whether category info is not empty. Maybe you can add an update your answer, so people would know what to do.Thanx for your help!

Comment: Thank you for your reply

Comment: It's been a while I asked for your help. How can I display subcategory links for each product too, do you possibly know? Because all my categories are now subcategories and subcategories are subsubcategories. Sounds complicated. I tried changing this code, but with no luck. Thank you in advance. @Mojtaba Sabeti