# Show product categories on the Search page

Tags: php, opencart

I'm using Opencart. I want to show which category the search product has searched for.

```
Normally: Search-> product name,
```

I want to show my results like that:

```
Search-> Category-> subcategory-> product name
```

Version: 2.1.0.1

Comment: You want to display each products categories in search results?

Comment: Yes exactly....

Comment: try this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40803997/opencart-to-show-category-for-each-product-in-search-results-page

Answer (score 0):

Go to your serach controller

```
catalog/controller/product/search.php
```

approx line number no. 247 replace this code

```
            $data['products'][] = array(
                'product_id'  => $result['product_id'],
                'thumb'       => $image,
                'name'        => $result['name'],
                'description' => utf8_substr(strip_tags(html_entity_decode($result['description'], ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8')), 0, $this->config->get('config_product_description_length')) . '..',
                'price'       => $price,
                'special'     => $special,
                'tax'         => $tax,
                'rating'      => $result['rating'],
                'href'        => $this->url->link('product/product', 'product_id=' . $result['product_id'] . $url)
            );
```

With this one

```
            $cats = $this->model_catalog_product->getCategories($result['product_id']);
            $sep = '';
            $catnames = '';

            foreach ($cats as $cat){

                $catarr = $this->model_catalog_category->getCategory($cat['category_id']);

                $catnames .= $sep.$catarr['name'];
                $sep = ', ';
            }

            $data['products'][] = array(
                'product_id'  => $result['product_id'],
                'thumb'       => $image,
                'name'        => $result['name'],
                'description' => utf8_substr(strip_tags(html_entity_decode($result['description'], ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8')), 0, $this->config->get('config_product_description_length')) . '..',
                'price'       => $price,
                'special'     => $special,
                'tax'         => $tax,
                'rating'      => $result['rating'],
                'href'        => $this->url->link('product/product', 'product_id=' . $result['product_id'] . $url),
                'category'    => $catnames
            );
```

And in your template file (I'm going to mention default theme path, if you're using any another theme then you can change it as per your theme)

```
catalog/view/theme/default/tempate/product/seach.tpl
```

You can simply call it in your loop using $product['category']

That's it!!